# What would be the equivalent in Golang of crypto.randomBytes(32) in the Node crypto package?

Tags: node.js, go

Hi guys I'm basically trying to recreate this node package:

https://github.com/seishun/node-steam-crypto/blob/master/index.js

In `golang` so I can make API calls to the Steam API that requires these encrypted `sessionKeys` and what not.

I was looking through the `crypto` package but there is so many different hashing methods to use I'm not sure which one would be the closest to the

`crypto.randomBytes(32)` in the node package.

Also the

`crypto.publicEncrypt()`

Sorry if this question is crap, not sure how else to word it as I haven't really dealt with this kind of stuff before. Any information would be great thanks.

Answer (score 5):

[`rand.Read`](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rand/#Read):

```
import "crypto/rand"
…
b := make([]byte, 32)
_, err := rand.Read(b)
```

Comment: what about the publicEncrypt? Thanks.

Comment: When I do `fmt.Println(rand.Read(b))` it just says 32, is that normal?

Comment: @Datsik: It stores the result in `b` and returns the number of bytes read (as well as an error – which you should check), so yes.